# Logitech Performance MX Model: 910-001105

Tags: mouse, logitech

my company gave me this mouse for work within dell laptop latitude 3490 running ubuntu 20.04 and i wonder if are there any drivers for this mouse because i want all of the buttons on the mouse to be working

Comment: maybe you can try this ---> https://itsfoss.com/piper-configure-gaming-mouse-linux/

Comment: this program just say "cannot find any devices"

Comment: Check out `Solaar` in the repos.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you could check to see if Ubuntu is registering any button presses on the extra mouse buttons. If it is then you should be able to map these buttons however you want using the `xbindkeys` tool.

To do the check run `xev` in a terminal, it will show a small window, when you move over the window or click on the window it will show the mouse move/click results in the terminal. So keep your mouse very still over the small window and click a button, you are looking for output like this which in my case is a press of button 3:

```
ButtonRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6000001,
    root 0x1b3, subw 0x6000002, time 93757188, (50,41), root:(100,155),
    state 0x410, button 3, same_screen YES
   
ButtonPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x6000001,
    root 0x1b3, subw 0x6000002, time 93769657, (50,41), root:(100,155),
    state 0x10, button 3, same_screen YES
```